# How to select last column without Null in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am facing an issue I cannot seem to find the solution of anywhere. I have a table in mySQL with following columns:

```
RoleDuty1
RoleDuty2
RoleDuty3
RoleDuty4
RoleDuty5
RoleDuty6
RoleDuty7
```

This table has just one row or record. I want to see which is the last column in the table which is ***Not NULL*?** meaning that I want to dynamically get **Column Name** `RoleDuty7` as an answer from mySQL, since all of the columns have some value other than Null inside them.

Anyone has any idea how can I do this?

Comment: You should rather change your table design.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the coalesce function is for:

```
SELECT COALESCE(RoleDuty1,RoleDuty2,RoleDuty3,RoleDuty4,RoleDuty5,RoleDuty6,RoleDuty7,'All null) as FIRST_NON_NULL
FROM aTable
```

Comment: This gives you the value in the column, not the column name

Comment: @kbball -- good point, if he really needs column name I've no idea how to help him.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a COALESCE with a bunch of CASE statements, like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(rd1, rd2, rd3, rd4, rd5, rd6, rd7)
FROM
(SELECT
 CASE WHEN roleduty1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'roleduty1' ELSE NULL END AS rd1,
 CASE WHEN roleduty2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'roleduty2' ELSE NULL END AS rd2,
 ....
 FROM t) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (
    CASE FirstNullColumn
        WHEN 'RoleDuty1' THEN 'None'
        WHEN 'RoleDuty2' THEN 'RoleDuty1'
        WHEN 'RoleDuty3' THEN 'RoleDuty2'
        WHEN 'RoleDuty4' THEN 'RoleDuty3'
        WHEN 'RoleDuty5' THEN 'RoleDuty4'
        WHEN 'RoleDuty6' THEN 'RoleDuty5'
        WHEN 'RoleDuty7' THEN 'RoleDuty6'
        ELSE 'RoleDuty7'
        END
) AS LastNonNullColumn
FROM (
    SELECT (
        CASE
            WHEN RoleDuty1 IS NULL THEN 'RoleDuty1'
            WHEN RoleDuty2 IS NULL THEN 'RoleDuty2'
            WHEN RoleDuty3 IS NULL THEN 'RoleDuty3'
            WHEN RoleDuty4 IS NULL THEN 'RoleDuty4'
            WHEN RoleDuty5 IS NULL THEN 'RoleDuty5'
            WHEN RoleDuty6 IS NULL THEN 'RoleDuty6'
            WHEN RoleDuty7 IS NULL THEN 'RoleDuty7'
            ELSE 'None'
        END
    ) AS FirstNullColumn
    FROM MyTable
)
```